# Timer inside callback React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, timer, callback

I've a list of items I need to individually wait time for:

```
const products = [{
    itemID: 1,
    name: 2,
    remainingTime: 600
},
{
    itemID: 12,
    name: 333,
    remainingTime: 300,
}]
```

I'm trying to add popup is any of the product remaining time <= 100s doing something like this:

```
products.map((product) => {
    let remainingTime = product.remainingTime;
    useEffect(() => {
        if (remainingTime <= 100){
            addPopup("Time Expiring")
        }
    }, [remainingTime])
})
```

But react won't let me add useEffect inside the map. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot have an `useEffect` inside a loop. See [Rules of Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). That has been said, can you please elaborate to make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

React updates all values if their parent are updated, so if products[1] are updated the whole map are "re-rendering" so you dont need to add a useEfect hook inside this .map, insted if you have a "countdown" living in each product you need to render a component and then use a useEffect inside this return so in mind i have this one

```
const ItemRenderer = ({ remainingTime }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
      // or if you wanna set a count down here are the site to
    if (remainingTime < 100) {
      // do your stuff if the prop change into this if
    }
  }, [remainingTime])
  return (
    <span>
      {remainingTime}
    </span>
  )
}


products.map(ItemRenderer)
```